# Transferring data between userscripts on different domains

Tags: javascript, userscripts

There's a way to [transfer data between pages on the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620163/transferring-information-between-userscripts-in-chrome), using localStorage, but I need to transfer data between different domains. In Chrome, I tried using symbolic links so the domains share the storage, but items set in one domain aren't found at the other domain until I reboot chrome. How do I transfer data between userscripts on different domains? I'll use any browser that'll work.

This'll only be for personal use

Comment: I'm not aware of any browser provided way that could solve this for you, there are some good reasons why this would be a bad thing (security, privacy, storage limits, security!, privacy!). However, I would imagine that if you were keen to solve it and didn't care too much about these things for your own userscript, you could post data to a different resource. e.g. you run the userscript on `website-a` and `website-b` and using AJAX they get/post data from/to `website-c`. Again, great for personal stuff, would get more complicated if this is something you want to share with other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would include both domains using [`@include`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules) and then use [`GM_getValue`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue) and [`GM_setValue`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) to store and retrieve the data.

I've also included an example on how to use the [`GM_registerMenuCommand`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_registerMenuCommand) function which opens a prompt when the user selects the option from the userscript addon popup.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Pinky
// @namespace    http://pinkyAndTheBrain.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      https://domain1.com
// @include      https://domain2.com
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==
/* global GM_getValue, GM_setValue, GM_registerMenuCommand */
/* jshint esnext:true */
(() => {
  'use strict';

  // get previous setting (or set to Pinky as default)
  let char = GM_getValue('character', 'Pinky');

  // do something fun!

  // called through the userscript addon
  GM_registerMenuCommand('Are you Pinky or Brain?', () => {
    const value = prompt('Enter "p" or "b"', char);
    if (value !== null) {
      // default to Pinky
      char = /^b/i.test(value) ? 'Brain' : 'Pinky';
      GM_setValue('character', char);
    }
  });

})();
```